# HeaderView tapping tableviewcell expand

Tags: ios, swift

I trying to expand the tableviewcell by tapping the header cell.
But I want to know how to pass the collapse bool with sections in header delegate function.
When I tap on header the delegate function is calling correctly.

Please correct.

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

```
//MARK: - IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var bottomView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var subcriptionTableview: UITableView!

var reloadSections: ((_ section: Int) -> Void)?
var isCollapsible = false
var isCollapsed = false

let imgArray = ["basic","standard","advanced","premium"]
let amtArray = ["$10 / month","$25 / month","$30 / month","$40 / month"]
let planArray = ["Basic","Standard","Advanced","Premium"]
let expandViewArray = ["Lorem ipsum is a dummy text content in a paragraph.","Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium.","At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos."]

//MARK: - LifeCycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    reloadSections = { [weak self] (section: Int) in
        self?.subcriptionTableview?.beginUpdates()
        self?.subcriptionTableview?.reloadSections([section], with: .automatic)
        self?.subcriptionTableview?.endUpdates()
    }
    
    subcriptionTableview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    subcriptionTableview.register(UINib(nibName: "SubsPlanHeader", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "SubsPlanHeader")
    subcriptionTableview.register(UINib(nibName: "ExpandTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "expandcell")
    
    bottomView.clipsToBounds = true
    bottomView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    bottomView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
    
}
```

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,HeaderViewDelegate {

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return planArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard isCollapsible else{
        return expandViewArray.count
    }
    
    if isCollapsed == true {
        return 0
    }else{
        return expandViewArray.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = subcriptionTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expandcell", for: indexPath) as! ExpandTableViewCell
    cell.labelPlanDetail.text = expandViewArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    let headerCell = subcriptionTableview.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "SubsPlanHeader") as! SubsPlanHeader
    headerCell.labelAmt.text = amtArray[section]
    headerCell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: imgArray[section])
    headerCell.labelPlanName.text = planArray[section]
    headerCell.labelLine.isHidden = true
    headerCell.delegate = self
    headerCell.section = section
    return headerCell
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}

func toggleSection(header: SubsPlanHeader, section: Int) {
    
    if isCollapsible {
        // Toggle collapse
        let collapsed = !isCollapsed
        isCollapsed = collapsed
        //  header.setCollapsed(collapsed: collapsed)
        
        // Adjust the number of the rows inside the section
        reloadSections?(section)
    }
    
}
```

}

UITableViewHeaderFooterView :

protocol HeaderViewDelegate: AnyObject {
func toggleSection(header: SubsPlanHeader, section: Int)
}

class SubsPlanHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

```
// MARK: - IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var subView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var labelAmt: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageArrow: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageCheck: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var labelPlanName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelLine: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

var section: Int?
weak var delegate: HeaderViewDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapHeader)))

}

@objc private func didTapHeader() {
    if let _section = section{
    delegate?.toggleSection(header: self, section: _section)
        print("touched")
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can't reached delegate method execution as you want in reason that you have got property `isCollapsible` always `false` since viewController initiated. And you are toggling it only when it is `true`

Any way instead of

```
let collapsed = !isCollapsed 
isCollapsed = collapsed
```

you can use

```
isCollapsed = !isCollapsed
```

since by tap on the header you always need to reload section for hide/unhide try to remove `if condition` and reconsider some code

just saw these strings:

```
var isCollapsible = false
var isCollapsed = false
```

my advise - try to refactor for simplifying. I don't know your goals, but it seems odd by first look